# How to replace the default page and tab of profiles in the user account?

Tags: views, navigation, 9

I installed the "Profile" module on my "Drupal 9" website. When I create a profile type, the module automatically creates a tab in the user account for each profile type.

For my profile type "projects" the user account tab displays the page for this profile type, with this path :

```
/user/ID/project/list
```

Here is the view added by the module :

[image]

Here are the tabs created in the user account :

[image]

I created a Views page with the following path to replace the default "Profile" module page for my "projects" profile type :

[image]

You have to click on "Projet" to display the profiles :

[image]

The problem is that with my custom page, the tabs disappear. How to replace the default page and keep the tabs ? I want the page to display with the default tab.

I need to create my own Views for each type of profile.

Comment: What's your Menu and Path configuration?

Comment: @prkos Here is the configuration of my Views and it sempbel correct, but the tabs do not appear https://ibb.co/gdVDrm9 and https://ibb.co/NygsdgK

Comment: You should update the question with new info, it's hard to find them in the comments. It seems you have your path set to a wrong level of tabs, since this isn't the default tab you don't need the `/list` part. You may also need to adjust the Parent if the Path fix doesn't work, set it to a User profile menu item, not the top level of User menu.

Comment: @prkos I haven't found the solution. I updated my question.